# SQL query to get a single user based on username or email

Tags: sql

I have a table `Users` with four columns like:

```
Users
- username
- email
- address
- name
```

Given a username and email, I want to find a single user in my table who has the same username and email, or the same username with the email not matching any other users, or the same email with the username not matching any other users.

For example, if this is my table:

```
username   email            address     name     id
jbrian     jbr@gmail.com     ""         John      1
gpaul                        ""         George    2
""         gpaul@gmail.com.  ""         George    3
""         tking@gmail.com.  ""         Tom       4
```

Searching for username `jbrian` and email `jbr@gmail.com` should return `id` 1.

Searching for username `gpaul` and email `gpaul@gmail.com` should return nothing, because they are for different users.

Searching for username `tking` and email `tking@gmail.com` should return `id` 4 because the email matches and there are no other matches for the username.

I put this together - `select users.id from users where username='gpaul' or email='gpaul@gmail.com' limit 1`

But this would always return one result. I'm not sure how to enforce the constraint that only one result should be returned, or else nothing should be returned.

Comment: You are using OR condition, OR condition will check that only one side of the OR conditions returns true if so that is why you will always have result. Try use AND instead of OR. Because AND will make sure that every condition must be TRUE otherwise it wont return anything

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 0):

For same username & email -> Pls change OR to AND

```
select users.id from users where username='gpaul' AND email='gpaul@gmail.com'
```

If you want to check for both, same username & email AND same username with different email, try this out

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = 'gpaul' AND id NOT IN(SELECT TOP 1 b.id FROM usersb WHERE username = 'gpaul' AND email = 'tking@gmail.com' ORDER BY id DESC)
```

Comment: But this wouldn't account for the case where email matches and username doesn't, as in `tking@gmail.com` above. In that case, it should still return a result for the email match.

Comment: @covfefe Please try the second query, I have edited my answer. Please modify the value of username and email accordingly. Don't just copy and run, value must according to the data in your database

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html
Limit clause is used to limit the number of rows returned.

```
select users.id from users where username='gpaul' or email='gpaul@gmail.com' limit 1
```

Therefore, the query cannot return more than 1 row.

OR: -> your query returns 1 row if either email or username not found, 2 if both are found (can be in different rows), and 0 if both username and email absent.

AND: -> your query returns 0 rows if email or username are not in the same row, and 1 if they are in the same row.

note: if there are repeating values of emails and names in the table, result can produce more rows. If that's the case you would want to make it unique to constrain the amount of rows you need as the output.

The query produces 0 rows if there is either email or username or the user_id's for email and username are different. And 1 row if its both.

```
select user_id from (select user_id 
               from users where username='gpaul' limit 1) x
intersect
select user_id from (select user_id 
               from users where email='gpaul@gmail.com' limit 1) x
```

Comment: The query with the intersect gives me an error at the `limit 1`:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "intersect"
LINE 1: ...elect * from users where username='gpaul' limit 1 intersect ...

If I remove the first `limit 1`, it works. Is there a way to keep the limit 1 on both queries?

Comment: Fixed it, it should work now

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable using `like` expression.

```
select id from users where email like concat(username, '%')
```